# How to output a value from database on selecting an option from dropdown using loop?

Tags: php, laravel, database, loops, drop-down-menu

I am new to laravel.

I have a data set from a database which is stored in a variable product_data.

| name | number_of_products | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-50k | 2 | 200 |
| 51-100k | 3 | 123 |
| 100-150k | 6 | 345 |
| 150-200k | 8 | 450 |

I want to write name as dropdown , on selecting a particular name the number of products and price should display as text . I wish to add another dropdown for quantity for each name , the quantity should be maximum of number of products.

For example: If I select a name 51-100k from the dropdown, the price 123 should display in text field and number of products 3 should display in a text filed and the quantity in dropdown should range from 1 to 3 . This fields should also save to another table in database with table name as bid_price with fields as name, number_of_products,bid_price, original_Price.

What I have tried is:

```
<div class="form-group row">    
     <label>Select Milege gap: </label>
<select class="form-select" name="mileage" id="mileage" onchange="getOption()">
    {% for p in product_data %}
    <option value="{{p.name}}">{{p.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>           
</div>
 <div class="form-group row">   
     <label>Avalaible Quantity: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly name="avaialbe_qty"/>
        
</div>
  <div class="form-group row">  
     <label>Quantity: </label>
<select class="form-select" name="quantity" id="quantity" >
    {% for p in product_data %}
    <option value="{{p.number_of_products}}">{{p.number_of_products}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>           
</div>                                  

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputBid" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" >Enter Bid Price</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputBid" name="bid"  />
    </div>
  </div>
            
 <script>
function getOption()
    {
        var select = document.getElementById('mileage');
        var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        document.getElementById('truck').value = option.value;
    }
</script>
```

How to show the corresponding price and number of products based on select value of dropdown.?

Comment: what's the problem with this code?

Comment: @GiacomoM My output is not fetching the corresponding data from the database

Comment: In this code, you're setting the value of selected option to a field having id truck. You're not fetching any data. Also, you want to input price on selecting an option, but this code will show the name in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for p in product_data %}
  <option value="{{p.number_of_products}}">{{p.number_of_products}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is Jinja not blade
in order to use blade

```
@foreach($product_data as $product)
  <option value="{{$product->number_of_products}}">{{$product->number_of_products}} - ${{$product->price}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I need price and number_products and name This code will display only number of products

Comment: @Binsha done edited

Comment: @Binsha I edited my answer please let me know if this not working for you

Comment: This is not the way  I want.

Comment: @Binsha I edited my answer please let me know if this not working for you

Comment: Please read the example description

Answer (score 0):

The below given snippet is an example to illustrate how to achieve your goal in plain php and javascript.
You may change it into Laravel Blade and front end of your choice.

Assume that you have the data as a PHP Array as given below.

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        "name" => "0-50k",
        "number_of_products" => 2,
        "price" => 200,
    ],

    [
        "name" => "51-100k",
        "number_of_products" => 3,
        "price" => 123,
    ],

    [
        "name" => "100-150k",
        "number_of_products" => 6,
        "price" => 345,
    ],

    [
        "name" => "150-200k",
        "number_of_products" => 8,
        "price" => 450,
    ]
];
?>
```

In the HTML

```
<!-- Including bootstrap for styling --!>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-1 p-5">
            <div class="text-success" id="summary"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-5 p-5">
            <div class="col-3">
                <select name="mileage" id="mileage" onchange="updatePage()" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <?php foreach ($data as $row) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" data-name="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" data-numberofprods="<?php echo $row['number_of_products']; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
                            <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type="text" id="truck" value="" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function updatePage() {
        var summEl = document.getElementById('summary')
        summEl.innerHTML = null;
        var select = document.getElementById('mileage');
        var selectedElem = select.options[select.selectedIndex]
        var val = selectedElem.value
        var outputEl = document.getElementById('truck');

        if (typeof val === 'undefined' || '' === val) {
            outputEl.value = '';
        }
        let name = selectedElem.getAttribute('data-name')
        let numOfProds = selectedElem.getAttribute('data-numberofprods')
        let price = selectedElem.getAttribute('data-price')
        outputEl.value = price;
        summEl.innerHTML = `Maximum ${numOfProds} ${name} products are available.`
    }
</script>
```

A note of Caution:

> This snippet uses the price and other details as a data-property.
> This can be manipulated by the anyone. So this is less secure and not recommended to use without server side validation.
> I have made this suggestion based on the limited information given in the question. The actual requirement is unknown.